# Drawing translucency drawable in Android, but black edge

Tags: android, canvas, alpha, drawable

I have the below image (the white bubble in the image) to draw in a canvas. When I draw the image using the code.., the image 's edge is getting black circle and rounded .. the edge's alpha is 0x00.

image.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);

image.draw(canvas);

Expected [image]    When I draw  [image]

How could I remove the black circle??? Is the image wrong?? or Anyone know the clue, Please give me a clue.. Thanks in advance..

^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your expected output taken from an image editor (Photoshop?) If so, that'll be the result of a 32-bit blend, whereas it looks like the alpha-blend on Android is being performed in 16-bits, hence the banding in the background, and halo around your image.

Presuming you're using `Bitmap` objects, you can check whether this is the case by calling `bitmap.getConfig()` to find their colour depth (from the `Bitmap.Config` enum).

**Edit**: One more thing that may be causing the halo - you say the edges of your sprite have an alpha of 0, but what  about the RGB values? Make sure the ARGB is set to full-white (ARGB 0x00ffffff) rather than black (ARGB 0x00000000).

Comment: Yes, it is from Fireworks. When I print the config, I got ARGB_8888. What does it mean???

Comment: ARGB_8888 means the bitmap is stored in memory using 32 bits for each pixel - 8 bits for the alpha, red, green and blue channels.